# Update null values column with values from the same column based on a query

Tags: sql

I have a table that has 2 columns, `SSN` and `StateID`.  There are duplicate rows with the same `SSN`, but not all rows have a `StateID`.  I want to select the rows that have a null `StateID`, and update it with the row with a matching `SSN`, and has a `StateID`.

Example of data

```
SSN           StateID 
123456789      XYZ 
123456789 
123456789
000000001      ABC 
000000001
```

I want to update the null values in `StateID` with the row value that does not have a null value.

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should fix your data model.  It is a bad idea to replicate data across multiple rows.  You should have a table with row per state and SSN and then use a join to connect them.

That said, in most databases you can do:

```
update t
    set stateid = (select max(t2.stateid) from t t2 where t2.ssn = t.ssn)
    where t.stateid is null;
```